# Dynamic type passing and instantiation -- how?

Tags: c#, dynamic

EDIT: changed `Activator`, still doesn't work.

So I'm pretty (very) new to C# and I'm pretty sure this is a dupe, but I've looked through the previous questions and I still can't work out all the points.

I am trying to reduce code smell by replacing some repeated code with a map over a generic list. Specifically, I have code that looks like

```
var fooNode = node as IFoo;
var barNode = node as IBar;
var bazNode = node as IBaz;
...

if(fooNode != null)
    return new FooThing();
if(barNode != null)
    return new BarThing();
if(bazNode != null)
    return new BazThing();
...
```

and I want to generalise it.

---

Here's my attempt:

```
var types = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    {typeof(IFoo), typeof(FooThing)},
    {typeof(IBar), typeof(BarThing)},
    ...
}

foreach(var entry in types)
{
    var castNode = node as entry.Key;
    return Activator.CreateInstance(entry.Value);
}
```

Naturally, it doesn't work: `The type or namespace name 'entry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Can you help? Is this sort of thing even possible in C#?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return Activator.CreateInstance(entry.Value);` --- the way you are using it you have to specify a compile-time type.

Comment: It's definitely possible. I just ran through a quick test of that code and the `Activator.CreateInstance` call works fine for me. The compiler being unable to find an iteration variable is weird. It seems something else may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
foreach(var entry in types)
{
    if (node != null && entry.Key.IsAssignableFrom(node.GetType()))
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(entry.Value);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you are confusing generic type parameters with runtime types and in particular the `Type` class.

If you know what a type will be at compile time then you can use the generic `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` method to create an instance of the underlying object - you can use things like type parameters so that this line of code doesn't need to know what the type is, for example:

```
T CreateObject<T>()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

However this just passes the buck.  In order to call this method the value of the type parameter `T` must be supplied *somewhere* - either way the compiler must be able to resolve `T` to a type (rather than a variable or method).

Conversely the `Type` class encodes type information at **runtime** such as its name or the assembly that a type is declared in.  `Activator.CreateInstance` also comes with an overload that allows you to supply an instance of `Type`:

```
object CreateObject(Type type)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

In your case it looks like you don't know what the types will be at compile time, so you will be mostly working with the `Type` class - you can use `typeof(MyClass)` to get an instance of the the corresponding `Type` for a class known at runtime, and `myObject.GetType()` to get type information for an object at runtime.

Comment: should probably be `entry.Value' --- the key is the interface type

Comment: @katrielalex What are you trying to do with that cast?  If you want to know whether an object is assignable from a given type then you can use `IsAssignableFrom`, for example `entry.Key.IsAssignableFrom(node.GetType())`

Answer (score 2):

```
var types = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    {typeof(IFoo), typeof(FooThing)},
    {typeof(IBar), typeof(BarThing)},
    ...
}

foreach(var entry in types)
{
    if(entry.Key.IsAssignableFrom(node.GetType()))
       return Activator.CreateInstance(entry.Value);
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding clearly your purpose for wanting to return different types from the same operation it will be hard to help. Maybe a little background information into the problem you are trying to solve??

I will assume that since you are attempting to return them interchangeably that  fooThing, BartThing and BazThing have the same interface. So I am assuming the following:

```
 public class FooThing : IMyOperations
 {

 }

 public class BarThing : IMyOperations
 {

 }

 public class BazThing : IMyOperations
 {

 }
```

You can define the relationship between the classes in another interface

```
 public interface IMyChoice
 {
      public bool IsSelected { get; }
      public IMyOperations GetWorker();
 } 

 public class ChoiceFoo : IMyChoice
 {


 }

 public class ChoiceBar : IMyChoice
 {

 }

 public class ChoiceBaz : IMyChoice
 {

 }
```

Now you can say

```
 foreach( var entry in choices)
 {
    if(entry.IsSelected)
    {
         return entry.GetWorker();
         //Can't remember if i need to break after return..doubt it
    }
 }
```